# C# format time "On The Hour"

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I need to format the time from a DateTime object as a string. The catch is, if the time is "on the hour" as in 12:00AM, 8:00PM, I need to trim the zeros and display 12AM or 8PM.

Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll have to do the check yourself:

```
dateTime.ToString(dateTime.Minute == 0 ? "Htt" : "H:mmtt");
```

Comment: +1 Cursed slow machine here at work. Typed everything in, watched chrome lock up, when it unlocked down popped your "1 new answer posted".

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm missing something, you can do this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
if (date.Minute == 0) {
   return date.ToString("Htt");
} else {
   return date.ToString("H:mmtt");
}
```

Obviously with the extra formatting wrapped around this. But that's the core of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
myDateTime.ToString("htt");
```